ASP.NET Core MVC Localization doesn't work when namespace is different
I'm starting now with ASP.NET - sorry if I'm asking a dumb thing.
In my company we use a default namespace for our projects, and the localization is not working properly. My string files resources are inside of my Resources/Strings folder.
I have been using the debug tool to check why my strings are not being found for my project.And I have seen that the program is searching inside of this address:
Resources.Strings.{my default namespace}.Controllers.HomeController

So, it's adding the Resources.Strings in front of my default namespace.
Here is part of my Program.cs:
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

// Add services to localization
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options =>
{
    options.ResourcesPath = "Resources/Strings";
});

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => 
{
    var suportedCultures = new[] 
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
        new CultureInfo("pt-BR")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
    options.SupportedUICultures = suportedCultures;
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization();

Here is a part of my HomeController:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var localizedString = _localizer["WelcomeMessage"]; 
        return View();
    }

    // {...}
}

I created a new project using the default namespace generated automatically when you create a new project in Visual Studio and it works perfectly with this same code, only using the standard namespace. Do you know what could be the problem or how can I deal with localization when we have different namespaces?
Thank you!
I have tried to add the complete namespace here but didn't work too.
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options =>
{
    options.ResourcesPath = "{Default Namespace}.Resources/Strings";
});



I could find a solution to my problem here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.rootnamespaceattribute.rootnamespace?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0
I created an AssemblyInfo.cs file and I applied add this code:
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

[assembly: ResourceLocation("Resource Folder Name")]
[assembly: RootNamespace("App Root Namespace")]

Now it is looking to the correct path.

this is the correct link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/provide-resources?view=aspnetcore-8.0
